# Is there any solution that currently exists for the graph automorphism problem in the general case?

Tags: graph-theory, computational-complexity, asymptotics

I was reading the Wikipedia pages on the graph automorphism, but I could not find any solution to the problem (Not even a brute force one). So, is it indeed true that no solutions exist for the general case of the automorphism problem?

P.S. Are there any significant uses of a solution to this problem in pure mathematics, or is the significance of such a solution mostly practical?

Thank you in advance.

Comment: There's an obvious brute force solution for finite graphs. Are you talking about infinite graphs?

Comment: Yes indeed. Is there currently any way to solve the graph automorphism problem in general for infinite graphs?

Answer (score 1):

It's not even possible to describe all infinite graphs. The only hope is to restrict to a computable subset. In that case it depends heavily on the subset.